# Hide folders in Mutt/Neomutt

Tags: mutt

I have searched on the internet for some time now. I want to hide folders in my Neomutt sidebar setup. I have unused folders there, they are not visible in my web interface of the mail.

- I am using outlook.com mail
- I am using NeoMutt 20171215
- I have installed Neomutt with *LukeSmithxyz*'s mutt-wizard

I am a beginner in Linux and Neomutt. Thank you.

Best regards,
Bithons

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways how to control what is on Your list of mailboxes or not. documented in neomuttrc(5) [here](https://neomutt.org/man/neomuttrc)

## imap_check_subscribed

a) Some e-mail providers allow You to control which folders are exposed via IMAP.

**GMAIL Settings > Labels > Show in IMAP** (checkbox per each label)

I didn't find any similar configuration inside outlook.com.

b) Or You can manage IMAP folder subscription inside the mutt mailbox browser:

1. go to browser:

   - **y**
   - **c?**
   - **:exec change-folder?**

one of the above should work. First two are default bindings they could be override by Your configuration. remaining are functions and should work whatever Your configuration is.

2. subscribe/unsubscribe folders under cursor:

   - **u** to unsubscribe selected folder
   - **s** to subscribe selected folder

If you don't see the folder you want to subscribe in the folder, try toggling the view between all and subscribed mailboxes using `<tab>`.

## mailboxes

`mailboxes +INBOX […]` which lists IMAP folders You want to check

Comment: When using `imap_check_subscribed` marking imap folders for (un)subscription seemed  to me persistent even after quitting neomutt.